# useEffect always work while using array dependency of boolean value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using useeffect to catch the action success message and show success message. It works fine, but success message shows always when i go to other pages and come back. I will add sample code..

```
const saveProfile = (userData) => dispatch(_UpdateProfile(userData));
const saveProfileSuccess = useSelector(state => state.UserReducer.saveProfileSuccess);

useEffect(() => {
    if (saveProfileSuccess) {
      showSuccessMessage("The user profile has been updated successfully.");
    }
  }, [saveProfileSuccess])
```

The scenario is...
I need to display success message and do some thing after calling "saveProfile" action method.
So the success result "saveProfileSuccess" will be true after save complete. the value of "saveProfileSuccess" value is true when we go to other pages and come back and it enter the useEffect and display success message again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you save a profile, then you are firing an action which updates the `saveProfileSuccess` store in the reducer.

Once this value is changed the useEffect gets triggered because its a dependency. When you go to a different route and come back to the page again you see the successMessage again because

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (saveProfileSuccess) {
      showSuccessMessage("The user profile has been updated successfully.");
    }
  }, [saveProfileSuccess])
```

The above useEffect runs when the **component is Mounted for the first time** and when ever there is a change in the saveProfileSuccess value.

So what you should be doing is you can add a clean up function in the useEffect, when unmounting from this component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => // fire your action here which sets the saveProfileSuccess to false
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your ask, you want to hold on to the `saveProfileSuccess` until the component unmounts and transitions to another page.

One solution could be to use a second "mounting" `useEffect` hook to clear the state when the component unmounts. Note this `useEffect` has an empty dependency array so it is run only once when the component mounts and strictly returns a cleanup function to clear the success status.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (saveProfileSuccess) {
    showSuccessMessage("The user profile has been updated successfully.");
  }
}, [saveProfileSuccess]);

useEffect(() => () => dispatch(clearSaveProfileSuccess()), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `state.UserReducer.saveProfileSuccess` is a global state, you have to set false manually ​on unmount the component. Or if the state are not referenced from external components, I recommend you to use local state such as `useState`.